# Call psql meta commands from a Node script?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, psql

Is there a way to call psql meta commands from a Node script? I'm trying to use `\d+ <table_name>`.

I'm aware that I can see the raw queries that psql is generating using `-E` and call those instead, but I was hoping for something a little less manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, not without calling `psql` itself and parsing out the information you want as text. I wouldn't recommend doing that, since text-parsing solutions tend to be pretty brittle.

Your best bet, as you mentioned, is to use the [schema tables to query out the information](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22368) you're looking for. Under the hood this is what `psql` is doing, it's just providing a convenient shortcut.